# How to timestamp data collected using PySerial and export to csv?

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, timestamp, pyserial

I'm trying to collect serial data from multiple devices, timestamp and export it to a .csv file. I want to write separate modules for each device such that they return the data to the main module and all the writing to csv is done in that.

The following program writes date and time to csv but not the data returned from the device module.

```
import time
import csv
from threading import Thread
import fio2

def Csv_creator():
    my_file = open('test_csv.csv', 'w+')

    with my_file:
        new_file = csv.writer(my_file)

def Timestamp():
    date_now = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
    time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return [date_now,time_now]


def Write_loop():
    Csv_creator()
    fio2.Initialize()

    while True:
        with open('test_csv.csv', 'a') as f:
            [date_now,time_now] = Timestamp()
            fio2_data = fio2.Reader()
            print fio2_data
            to_write = [date_now,time_now,fio2_data]
            csv_file = csv.writer(f)
            csv_file.writerow(to_write)     

t = Thread(target=Write_loop)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

raw_input("Press any key to stop \n")
```

The device module is as shown below. It works fine on it's own but I have a hard time making it return the value and have it written onto the csv file.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM6",
                    baudrate=2400,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                    parity =serial.PARITY_ODD,
                    timeout=1,
                    writeTimeout =1)


def Initialize():
    global ser
    try:
        ser.isOpen()
        print("\n Serial is open")
    except: 
        print ("Error: serial Not Open")

def Reader():
    global ser
    if (ser.isOpen()):

        try:                    
            x = ser.readline().decode()
            x = (x)
            return x
        except:
            return "unable to print"
    else: 
        return "cannot open serial port"
```

Comment: In the with statement within the Write_loop() function, you have a badly formatted print statement.  I don't know the fio2 module, Is the method: Reader() all you need to extract the data?

Comment: I used the print statement to check if the Fio2 module was returning data. It's not something I need. And yes, the reader function basically reads from the port and returns the data to the main module.

Comment: Therefore it should be ‘ print(fio2_data) ‘ the formatting of both pieces of code is not consistent. One for Python2 and the other for Python 3

Comment: Oh that's a typo. Sorry, I have corrected it in my code. However, I'm still not able to write the data onto the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to remove some garbage letters that were associated with the decimal values. First, I change the received data to string and replaced the garbage letters. Here's how I changed it:

```
[date_now,time_now] = Timestamp()
fio2_data = str(fio2.Reader()).replace("\r\n","")
fio2_data = fio2_data.replace("\x000","")
write_list = [date_now,time_now,fio2_data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than opening the file each time in your loop, I would suggest moving it outside:

```
with open('test_csv.csv', 'a') as f:
    csv_file = csv.writer(f)

    while True:
        date_now, time_now = Timestamp()
        fio2_data = fio2.Reader()
        csv_file.writerow([date_now, time_now, fio2_data])
```

Comment: I moved it outside the loop and removed the thread. Replaced the while loop with a for loop that runs for 20 seconds. But it only writes the time details but not the data. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.